# while creating Custom Image Html Helper it throws System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: virtualPath'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

while creating Custom Image Html Helper it throws

> "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   virtualPath'"

```
public static IHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, string alt, string height, string width, params string[] allClasses)
{
    TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("img");
    tb.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(src));//throws error
    tb.Attributes.Add("alt", alt);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(height) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(width))
    {
        StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(height))
            value.AppendFormat("height:{0};", height);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(width))
            value.AppendFormat("width:{0};", width);

        tb.Attributes.Add("style", value.ToString());
    }
    if (allClasses?.Any() ?? false)
        tb.Attributes.Add("class", string.Join(" ", allClasses));

    return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

Comment: Well... don't pass it a `null` value?

Comment: `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(src)` with `src` has null value will throwing error. How you're actually using the helper in Razor?